# Mac App Sandbox - NSHomeDirectory() issues

Tags: cocoa, sandbox

I just sandboxed my Mac App and in my app I save images in the documents folder. I have this file URL: `file:///Users/myUser/Documents/myApp/Images/logo.jpg`

After my sandbox I end up using NSHomeDirectory() instead of going directly to the Documents folder. The problem with this is that it strips out the `file://`. Basically, how do I append `file://` to the URL?

This is what `NSHomeDirectory()` gives me:

```
/Users/myUser/Library/Containers/com.company.myApp/Data/myApp/Images/logo.jpg
```

Later on, the user can choose another directory and then I can use the power box, but before the user does that I need to be able to read/write files to the home directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSHomeDirectory()` returns an `NSString`, not an `NSURL`. You can convert it into an `NSURL` by calling:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()];
```

[See here for docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBGFBJ).

You may also want to use [`NSHomDirectoryForUser(userName)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW3) instead of `NSHomeDirectory()`.

Comment: of course. I think I was too tired when working on this. Thanks!